# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in mamp

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mamp, mysqlnd

I am running MAMP on windows. php_mysqli.dll is enabled in the php.ini file.

Along with that, in php info it says the mysqlnd is enabled:

[image: phpinfo mysqlind]

Here is what my php looks like:

```
$connection = connect();
if($stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '?'")){
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
}
```

The line `$result = $stmt->get_result()` throws the error

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()

Any guesses why `get_result()` is not working?

This is different than the questions already asked because all of the solutions refer to mysqlind not being enabled although, in my case it is.

Comment: **My solution:** Stop using MAMP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you switch to PDO you can use [`fetchAll`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjn-YCS1JzOAhVNxGMKHatHCA0QFggeMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fphp.net%2Fmanual%2Fen%2Fpdostatement.fetchall.php&usg=AFQjCNEsiJJo3rFxclTiuaHpcWLA4NaJiw) instead. PDO is better than mysqli for several reasons, one including the ability to pass in arrays as parameters before execution.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably do something like download the php install from [here](http://www.php.net/): and use the MAMP php directory as the install location.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thank you, I will take that into account for further activities